# Any Linux Kernel configuration required to be enabled in OS for Inotify to work?

Tags: linux-kernel, inotify

I've been having trouble researching this topic so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Are there any Kernel configurations required to be enabled in the OS for Inotify to work? What options do I need to enable in the .config file of Linux kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER`.  Here's the help text associated with that kernel option:

> CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER:
>
> Say Y here to enable inotify support for userspace, including the
> associated system calls.  Inotify allows monitoring of both files
> and directories via a single open fd.  Events are read from the
> file descriptor, which is also select()- and poll()-able.
>
> Inotify fixes numerous shortcomings in dnotify and introduces several
> new features including multiple file events, one-shot support, and
> unmount notification.
>
> For more information, see <file:Documentation/filesystems/inotify.rst
>
> If unsure, say Y.
>
> Symbol: INOTIFY_USER [=y]
> Type  : bool
> Defined at fs/notify/inotify/Kconfig:2
>   Prompt: Inotify support for userspace
>   Location:
>     -> File systems
> Selects: FSNOTIFY [=y]

I found this by:

- Navigating to the kernel sources
- Doing a `make menuconfig`
- Hitting `/` to do a search
- Typing `inotify` and pressing `Enter`

Comment: Thank you Andy, your answer is extremely helpful!